# "smtp; 550 Messages should have one or no Reply-To headers, not 2" on Mailgun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, mailgun

Emails to one of my users are periodically failing on Mailgun with the error `smtp; 550 Messages should have one or no Reply-To headers, not 2`:

I can't see my `Reply-To` header in the Mailgun logs, but I'm reasonably certain I can only be sending one email in the `Reply-To` header. Here's my Ruby on Rails code that conditionally sets that header:

```rb
    folder_emails = @fileuploads.map do |f|
      f.folder =~ /([\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+)/i
      Regexp.last_match(1)
    end.compact.uniq
    email_params[:reply_to] = folder_emails.first if folder_emails.size == 1
```

If the `:reply_to` field isn't set in that code, it defaults to a default `reply-to` defined in my `ApplicationMailer`.

I'm using the `mailgun-ruby` gem to deliver mail (`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun`).

Comment: `Rails.logger.info email_params[:reply_to]` and check your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! tl;dr: I needed to add quotes around the name of my email addresses.

Instead of:

```rb
default from: "Robot@Fileinbox <robot@finbox.com>",
        reply_to: "Christian@Fileinbox <christian@finbox.com>"
```

I needed:

```rb
default from: %("Robot@Fileinbox" <robot@finbox.com>),
  reply_to: %("Christian@Fileinbox" <christian@finbox.com>)
```

---

Mailgun support said it was getting sent two `Reply-To` headers:

```
Reply-To: "Christian@Fileinbox" <christian@finbox.com>

Reply-To: Christian@Fileinbox <christian@finbox.com>
```

which is weird, because I was definitely only sending one (logging my `email_params[:reply_to]` just showed the one address). I think somewhere in the pipeline something got upset that the `Christian@Fileinbox` name part of the email and added an extra header with the quotes.

Adding quotes and removing the email suppression in Mailgun fixed it! My user is getting emails again :D